# autocmd for the event: "the first time a buffer is entered"

Tags: buffers, autocmd

I know that the autocommand `autocmd BufEnter` will be triggered every time a buffer is entered. Is there a way to define an `autocmd` that will be triggered only the first time a buffer is entered?

Comment: Depending on your use case,  `BufReadPost` (aka `BufRead`) might  be an option.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate? `BufReadPost` and `BufRead` are triggered every time a buffer is read, not just the first time.

Comment: But how often do you read the file into a buffer during a editing session? Maybe you should describe what you want to do.

Comment: My workflow usually involves having several buffers open, and switching between them using `:bn` and `:bp`. So I'm looking for a way to execute a command when I enter a buffer that I haven't entered before.

Comment: Set a buffer-local variable the first time the event triggers. Then the following times check for the existence of the variable

Comment: How about combination of ```BufferEnterPost``` and buffer variable like so ```let b:already_been_here=1```

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That was also my best idea at this point. Do you think you could submit an answer?

Comment: FWIW, I would recommend using **`autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile ...`** by default. That will also run the command when you start a _new file_ matching the pattern. More often than not, that is the behaviour I really want.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment

> My workflow usually involves having several buffers open, and switching between them using :bn and :bp. So I'm looking for a way to execute a command when I enter a buffer that I haven't entered before.

If you start Vim with several files, they are not read into memory immediately at startup. The file is only read when you enter the buffer.

So you can use the autocmd event "BufReadPost".

Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * echo strftime("%c")
```

Then open Vim with multiple *existing* files.

This will print a timestamp immediately on startup, as you entered the first buffer.

Then it will print a timestamp on every `:bn`, as you are entering a yet unvisited buffer (and it's file is read). If you use `:bp` to return to a file you already visited, no timestamp will be printed. 
Also no timestamp when you reached the end of the list and `:bn` brings you to the first file.

Note:

- only works when `hidden` is set
- the autocmd also fires when you reload a file (with `:e`)
- is not executed for new files, as there is no file to read yet

Comment: I don't think that command works as you've described. That command will print a timestamp every time you visit a buffer, whether it has been entered or not.

Comment: You don't think or you tested it?

Comment: I tested it. Does it work different for you?

Comment: @wxyz I just retested it. Started Vim with 4 _existing_ files and it works as I described. But it has drawbacks: If you reload a file (`:e`) it will fire again. Your own answer doesn't do that and also works with non-existing files.

Comment: This answer only works as described if you have `hidden` set. With `nohidden` (Vim's default) the command triggers every time you switch buffer.

Comment: @joeytwiddle You are right! I didn't think about that. Updated.

Comment: If you don't have `'hidden'` enabled you probably aren't using Vim right. ;) (Seriously, though.)

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create a buffer-local variable the first time a buffer is entered, and then check to see if that variable exists the following times that buffer is entered:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if !exists('b:has_been_entered') | 
    \ let b:has_been_entered = 1 | call input('First time entered!') | endif
```

<sup>*</sup>note: this answer is based on [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19927/autocmd-for-the-event-the-first-time-a-buffer-is-entered#comment34866_19927)